# What is the method to be able to use the mobile metamask app as a support for mobile chrome?

Tags: metamask, dapps, connections

So this one is incredibly hard to search for because it returns so many generic posts about how to install MetaMask on a chrome browser and various other things.

My query is about how many dapps are now able to function in chrome mobile browser using the MetaMask mobile app as a sidekick. So the user in chrome can essentially connect their wallet and complete purchases in chrome.

An example would be the AltSignals presale, where hitting the connectButton in a mobile chrome browser will open the MetaMask app and prompt the connection. When the connection is complete, MetaMask will send you back to chrome where you’ll be able to continue there.

I know people could just use the website/dapp directly through MM but in keeping accessibility there should still be functionality in the chrome mobile browser rather than having dead buttons that don’t do anything.

Thanks!

Comment: It isn't a new thing to use a website from your regular phone browser, to open an app on your phone. Metamask has a browser in its app, but it has always been preferable to use the browser on a phone to connect to the wallet.

Comment: Regardless, my question was about how this is achieved? I can't find any useful documentation or guidance about it. I mean opening another app with your browser is one thing, but tacking on wallet and transaction requests too?

Answer (score 0):

It is https://walletconnect.com/. From the browser an webapp can launch a wallet with universal links. The wallet and the webapp will connect using the walletconnect protocol as intermediary.